azure android speech sdk failed to get synthesised audio of translation result
Body:
Hi, my translation app is using azure android speech sdk. The input is audio. The output includes translated text and synthesised audio. It works well for years. In last few days (about Nov, 2024), it can not get synthesised audio. The text result is still good. It looks like:

TranslationRecognizer.synthesizing didn't response. I wonder if it's a server issue for I see this log. 11-06 13:23:46.038: E/oqin.translato(3609): netdebug 000000000.093726285 counter:9 ret:-1 connectErrno:115 latencyMs:0 addr:20.189.108.93 port:443 processname:oqin.translator

I am from China and the app is using in China mainland.
My application uses Microsoft azure speechservice android sdk. The code should be good because it works well for years. I hoped someone from Azure team can see this question so I attached tag "azure-speech". I got help from them in this way before.
Here is the document link I followed.
It's a mission impossible to provide you "minimal reproducible example" because that means to create another Android app which requires authentication security key to run SDK service which I couldn't public it.
It's an Android app which uses Azure SpeechService SDK. I just call sdk method with input and listen to out put. The log above is printted by SDK instead of my code. Here are some pseudo code I can provided:
  TranslationRecognizer mTranslationRecognizer = new TranslationRecognizer(config, audioInput);

  mTranslationRecognizer.recognized.addEventListener(new EventHandler<TranslationRecognitionEventArgs>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Object o, TranslationRecognitionEventArgs e) {
        // return text translation result.
        // it works good. return translated text
    }
    mTranslationRecognizer.synthesizing.addEventListener(new EventHandler<TranslationSynthesisEventArgs>() {
    @Override
    public void onEvent(Object o, TranslationSynthesisEventArgs e) {
        // return synthesized audio of text translation result above.
        // !!!! PROBLEM HERE: NOT return, since about Nov 1
    }

Please let me know what else I can do to pass the re-evaluation.
Thanks!

Have you checked the key and region are correct and speech service is available in the Azure Portal?

The key and region is correct. The app works well for 3 years and I still can get translated text result now. The problem is audio result not returned. The issue occurred since Nov

Can you provide MainActivity.java code in the question?

I have provided pseudo code above. It called azure sdk api. What do you expect in MainActivity?

I am asking about the MainActivity code from your Android project. Can you provide your GitHub repository?

Is this an Android project from Android Studio that you are trying to run or anything else?

I am experiencing exactly the same problem. Only started recently. No change on my code (I use C#). If anyone from Microsoft is seeing this, please investigate.  I posted a question on the MS forum as well.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2122539/translationrecognizer-has-stopped-sending-synthesi

@Billy You can raise a new question regarding your issue.

Cool. You can find it here. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/2681
